# Swift/OS X - Remove Application Title Bar and Add Custom Close Button

Tags: swift, macos, button, titlebar

I'm working on a little mac app where I want a pretty specific style for the window. I want to remove the application's menu bar completely, and then go about adding a custom close button. (Just a little white 'X' with no borders.) The reason I want this is I'm looking to make the application's background image cover the entire window, not just the view controller area and a gray title bar splotched above. So far, my window controller contains this:

```
self.window!.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
self.window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
self.window!.movableByWindowBackground  = true
```

All this does is remove the gray bar, but the buttons are left just where they were.

Thanks for reading, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show/hide window buttons would want to set the visibility of [**`NSWindowButton`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSWindowButton):

> These constants provide a way to access standard title bar buttons:

```
enum NSWindowButton : UInt {
    case CloseButton
    case MiniaturizeButton
    case ZoomButton
    case ToolbarButton
    case DocumentIconButton
    case DocumentVersionsButton
    case FullScreenButton
}
```

So you would likely use something such as this to set this visibility:

```
self.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton)?.hidden = true
```

Any other constants you want to prevail would likely work the same way. You would then set your new custom close button for example to the applications first responder [**`terminate`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:) function.

Comment: As soon as I get home I'll give this a try - If it works I'll mark it correct. :)